# Different Calculation Methods for Theoretical Quantiles of Q-Q Plot

Tags: normal-distribution, quantiles, qq-plot

There seem to be at least two different methods to calculate the theoretical quantiles in a Q-Q plot. In the following, the normal distribution is assumed to be the theoretical distribution.

1. Split the range (0,1) into q-quantiles where q is the number of samples in the sample distribution and then get the corresponding values from the theoretical distribution, e.g., like shown [here](https://www.statisticshowto.com/q-q-plots/) (this is also the way it is done in `qqplot` in `R`)?
2. Calculate the theoretical quantiles $q_i$ via the z-score normalization of each sample using the empirical mean ($\hat{\mu}$) and the empirical standard deviation ($\hat{\sigma}$) of the sample, i.e., $q_i = \frac{x_i - \hat{\mu}}{\hat{\sigma}}$ where $x_i$ is the i-th sample.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of the respective methods? Should one be strictly preferred over the other?

Comment: Could you explain how (2) works?  It doesn't even look like it will give you values in the interval $[0,1].$

Comment: 1. there was a missing equal sign in the formula; i corrected it
2. true, it won't. as far as i understand each observation is a cut point of a quantile and you just normalize this cut point so it matches the standard normal distribution. [Here](https://matheplanet.com/default3.html?call=viewtopic.php?topic=181581) is an example (unfortunately, it's in German)

Comment: How could those possibly be considered "theoretical" when they use only the data?  These are *standardized empirical* quantiles.  They are what you compare to the theoretical quantiles when you are constructing a Normal probability plot.

Comment: But the standardized quantiles are not even needed for comparison in 1. right? I could just plot the observations with the original scale against the theoretical quantiles. I added an example of the calculation of 2. in my previous comment.

Comment: My best guess is that wherever you write "theoretical" we should read "empirical," for then your question makes sense.  The two methods differ according to what units of measure you use for the data: the units as given or standardized units.  Because the Normal family is a location-scale family, changing units makes no difference.  For other families a change of units could make a difference.

Comment: when re-reading the linked post, I am actually not sure what exactly is going on there... to summarize everything: the axis that indicates the value of the sample can be either plotted with the original scale of the observed values or with normalized values. the values of the theoretical distribution are obtained as in 1. to get the corresponding value for a quantile, I either have to look it up in a standard normal table or use software (e.g., `qnorm` in R), right?

Comment: The site you link to has been a great source of questions here on CV because it hosts so many only-partly-correct "explanations."  A good strategy is to find a better explanation.  A site search for [probability plotting point answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=probability+%22plotting+point%22) turns up a few posts that might help you.